Which evidences do we have that general relativity works at large scales?
Recently I've been reading Pedro Ferreira's SciComm book The Perfect Theory: A Century of Geniuses and the Battle over General Relativity. At one of the last chapters, which discusses modified theories of gravity, the author mentions how the main tests of general relativity happened using solar system physics (and I'd say that most tests I know of use the Schwarzschild solution), which means there is a chance general relativity fails at large scales (cosmological scales, for example). Ferreira uses this to justify the interest in theories of modified gravity and that perhaps dark matter and dark energy are just consequences of trying to apply general relativity in a regime in which it does not really work.
While I'm quite familiar with general relativity and I don't know much about modified theories, I noticed that I am also not familiar with tests of general relativity beyond the classic tests using Schwarzschild, and more recently the results from LIGO using gravitational waves and from the EHT collaboration also using black hole spacetimes. Furthermore, Ferreira's book was written about ten years ago, so I guess that while his argument could be true back then, it might no longer be. This motivates my question: what is the current status of experimental evidence supporting general relativity at very large scales? (I'm leaving "very large" intentionally ambiguous to encompass anything that falls outside the tests I mentioned).

Does a gravitational lens 9.4 billion light years away count?

@LeeMosher Not really, since the gravitational field of the lens is quite small (in comparison), the rest is just light propagation.

@A.V.S. But the observation of Einstein rings does show that GR “works” at galactic scales. Given the uncertainties in the matter distribution producing the lens it isn’t a very stringent test though.

Well then I'm kind of in the dark regarding what "is" and "is not" evidence that general relativity "works" at large scales.

Well, the $\Lambda$ CDM model is the standard model of cosmology used today, and it assumes general relativity. What it explains is mentioned on the first page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model

@LeeMosher, I am not sure by saying "in the dark", it is meant to be a pun. But "dark" voodoo is the state of art in current cosmology: whenever general relativity does not work, you can always conjure up certain "dark matter", "dark energy", or "dark ice-cream" to make it work. Everything is just fine and dandy, right?

@Avantgarde I'm familiar with that, but Ferreira's point was that perhaps modified gravity could describe the Universe in large scales without the need for a dark sector

In the absence of a detailed answer here is a link to Living Review: Testing general relativity in cosmology.

@NíckolasAlves Yes sure, there are a couple of modified gravity theories, like MOND, massive gravity, etc. that try to explain gravity at large distances in a different way. Of course, no one knows what the "correct" theory is, but it's safe to say that Lambda CDM is the most well-accepted and studied of all.

@Avantgarde Oh, I absolutely agree. Lambda CDM is surely the most widely accepted, but my curiosity is about to which extend we know it is right vs we believe it is right

Generally the way astrophysicists/cosmologists test variation in fundamental physics theories is to add a parameter to their models to describe this variation and see what observational effects it has when it is non-zero. For modified gravity a popular theory is f(R) gravity, where we alter the standard  GR action by adding another term which is a function of the Ricci scalar (a single number representing curvature at a point):
$$S = \int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\frac{R+f(R)}{16 \pi G}$$.
There are lots of potential f(R) functions you could choose, but we can try our best to be agnostic and Taylor expand f(R). Because we are talking about cosmology (and not physics near black holes or something like that) we $R<<1$ and we can stick to looking at first/second order corrections which be be parametrized like:
$$B \propto \frac{f''(R)}{1+f'(R)}$$.
If we find B is consistent with zero, that means that first/second order there is no note-able modification to gravity and GR is consistent.
Now we want to find a probe at large scales to test this one. One test is something called the galaxy power spectrum; it basically says how much to galaxies cluster at different scales. We have theoretical predictions for this, and we can include this $B$ term to see how it effects things. We can then compare to data and see whether or not we detect $B \neq 0$. This was done in Dossett et al. 2014 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3980.pdf) where they found that the available data was consistent with $B = 0$. A significant amount of the constraining power was from k~0.1 - 0.2 (h/Mpc), which corresponds to clustering at scales greater than 1 Mpc.
Similar analysis were done with other cosmological probes, including number of galaxy clusters at given sizes: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.95.023521
Results from the Planck satellite studying the CMB: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.88.027502
Data from cosmic shear surveys (i.e. the very subtle bending of galaxy shape due to gravitational lensing):
https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.083527
Plus lots of others...
No signs of anything exciting yet!
